# looking for events for datagridview

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

i am creating UserControl of DatagridView
and i am looking for the event of the field leave 
i mean on lost focus of any of the fields

as example:

[image]

you see it on edit mode(on first row at LastName), i wanna use event everytime i lost focus after editing any field 
which events i can use?

i cant use `datagridview.click` cause it only if i lost focus on another column but i wanna to if i click on the "second on" button that still do lost focus

edit moreover i need In addition 1 more event
on error, i mean if i put in int field i write letter i wanna it show me error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [DataGridView.CellEndEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellendedit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event

Comment: ty found and it work perfect
can you help me again i wanna find event that happen or error or before it edit the column/row
like if i enter string to Int i wanna event to check it or event that happen on error

Comment: [See if this helps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.dataerror%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thank you these 2 they perfect!!!! :)

private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            ad.update();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
        {
           e.Cancel = false;
            MessageBox.Show("שגיאה בסוג נתונים");
        }